# Which form is correct? both windows jamb or both window jambs

Tags: grammar

**both windows jamb** needs to be exchange or **both window jambs** need to be exchanged?

Comment: *Both jambs need to be replaced*, therefore *Both window jambs need to be replaced*. It's possible, I suppose, for two windows to share a window jamb, but then it's unlikely that you'd use *both*.

Comment: @choster But you could have "Both windows' jamb needs to be replaced". The question needs more context, describing the arrangement of windows and jambs and exactly what needs to be replaced.

Comment: That would be too easy to hear as _Both windows jam; needs to be replaced_

Comment: Assuming it's only one window, it has two "window jambs".

Answer (score 1):

Since jamb means "a board that forms the side of a door or window", in your phrase "window jamb" jamb is the noun and window is used effectively as a an adjective which determines which kind of jamb is being referred to. As a result, it is jamb which is modified to the plural form, and "window jambs" is the correct version.